# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith' in selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to identify a unique attribute of the following element from [this page](https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=all&ad_type=all&country=ALL&q=%22%20%22&search_type=keyword_exact_phrase&media_type=all).

```html
<div aria-busy="false" aria-controls="js_10f" class="x1i10hfl xjqpnuy xa49m3k xqeqjp1 x2hbi6w x972fbf xcfux6l x1qhh985 xm0m39n x9f619 x1ypdohk xe8uvvx xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr x1mh8g0r x2lwn1j xeuugli x16tdsg8 xggy1nq x1ja2u2z x1t137rt x6s0dn4 x1ejq31n xd10rxx x1sy0etr x17r0tee x3nfvp2 xdl72j9 x1q0g3np x2lah0s x193iq5w x1n2onr6 x1hl2dhg x87ps6o xxymvpz xlh3980 xvmahel x1lku1pv xhk9q7s x1otrzb0 x1i1ezom x1o6z2jb xo1l8bm x108nfp6 x1v911su x1y1aw1k xwib8y2 x1ye3gou xn6708d" role="button" tabindex="0" xpath="1"><span class="x8t9es0 x1fvot60 xxio538 x1heor9g xq9mrsl x1h4wwuj x1pd3egz xeuugli xh8yej3"><div class="x78zum5"><div class="x1qvwoe0 xjm9jq1 x1y332i5 xcwd3tp x1jyxor1 x39eecv x6ikm8r x10wlt62 x10l6tqk xuxw1ft x1i1rx1s" data-sscoverage-ignore="true">Open Dropdown</div><div class="xeuugli x2lwn1j x6s0dn4 x78zum5 x1q0g3np x1iyjqo2 xozqiw3 x19lwn94 x1hc1fzr x13dflua x6o7n8i xxziih7 x12w9bfk xl56j7k xh8yej3"><div class="x3nfvp2 x120ccyz x1heor9g x2lah0s x1c4vz4f" role="presentation"><div class="xtwfq29" style="width: 16px; height: 16px; -webkit-mask-image: url(&quot;https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yq/r/Kn2aEYm6jwh.png&quot;); -webkit-mask-position: -34px -195px;"></div></div>​</div></div></span></div>
```

I decided to use `get_attribute('aria-controls')` as I had done before to verify the current element, however since this attributes value is different for each box/ad on the page, but only after the `js_` starting text; I found using the `startwith()` function would help.

However as you will see in my code snippet below, it produces the error shown in the title.

Minimum reproducible example -> (code issue on line `if current_element.get_attribute('aria-controls').startswith("js_")`

```py
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

# A function to utilize Selenium to crawl the Meta Ads Library and grab needed ads links 
def get_facebook_ads():

    past_date = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=3)).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    meta_cta_buttons = ['Get Offer', 'Get offer', 'Open Link', 'Open link', 'Order Now', 'Order now', 'Save', 'Shop Now', 'Shop now', 'Subscribe', 'Learn More', 'Learn more', 'Contact Us', 'Contact us', 'Download']
    unique_store_urls = set()

    try:
        # Initialize the browser and navigate to the page
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
        browser.get("https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=all&ad_type=all&country=ALL&q=%22%20%22&sort_data[direction]=desc&sort_data[mode]=relevancy_monthly_grouped&search_type=keyword_exact_phrase&media_type=all")
        # (In working order): Look for keyword, make it clickable, clear existing data in box, enter new info, keep page open for 10 seconds
        search_box = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Search by keyword or advertiser']")))
        search_box.click()
        search_box.clear()
        search_box.send_keys("" "" + Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(3)

        # Now we must go through each ad tablet and output `unique` CTA urls
        current_element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//body/div/div/div[@role='main']/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]")
        current_element.click()
        current_element.click()
        
        # actual tabbing process, with a starting point and the next element being reassigned to the initial, to tab to
        ads_traversed = 0
        new_ad = 0
        while(True):
            current_element.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
            WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//body/div/div/div[@role='main']/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]")))
            current_element = browser.switch_to.active_element
            
            if current_element.get_attribute('aria-controls').startswith("js_"):
                print("New ad - Traversing...\n")
                new_ad += 1
            else:
                print("still traversing...")

            # check for a set of keywords when a CTA button is targeted, if matched then extract URL from source    
            if current_element.get_attribute('role') == "button" and current_element.get_attribute('aria-busy') == "false" and current_element.get_attribute('tabindex') == '0':
                button_text = current_element.text
                if button_text in meta_cta_buttons:
                    ads_traversed += 1
                    print("Ad traversed! Going next...\n")
                    parent_element = current_element.find_element(By.XPATH, "..")
                    while (True):
                        if parent_element.tag_name != 'a':
                            # moves up element ancestry chain 
                            parent_element = parent_element.find_element(By.XPATH, "..") 
                        else:
                            cta_url = parent_element.get_attribute('href')
                            # store links in a set
                            unique_store_urls.add(cta_url)
                            break
                else:
                    continue
            else:
                continue
            try:
                # to look for the loading page data as part of infinite scroll
                spinner_element = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@role='progressbar']//*[name()='svg']")))
                end_of_page_element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Ad Library API')]")
                if spinner_element:
                    print("Spinner exists")
                    time.sleep(5)
                # if its at the footer, it means no data was loaded in time
                elif current_element == end_of_page_element:
                    break
            except TimeoutException:
                print("Spinner doesn't exist")
                continue

            # if ads_observed > 0:  #the top element will be hit every time, but a cta button will at times not exist, meaning that ad was just run past without stopping

        # prints numbered list of urls
        print("\n")
        for index, value in enumerate(unique_store_urls, start=1):
            print(f"{index}. {value}")            
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        browser.quit() 
        return unique_store_urls

def main():
    # Step 1 - get_facebook_ads() with an open search query -> (" ")
    get_facebook_ads()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `current_element.get_attribute('aria-controls')` returned None.  Therefore `current_element` must be something different than the example you showed at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occuring because when you are calling get_attribute() for one of the elements it is returning a `None` element which you cannot use .startswith() on. To fix you could do something like this

```
if not current_element.get_attribute('aria-controls'): # to catch those with None as a response
    print("still traversing...")
elif current_element.get_attribute('aria-controls').startswith("js_"):
    print("New ad - Traversing...\n")
    new_ad += 1
else:
    print("still traversing...")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I see what you mean. Was initially going to utilize a try:except. However based on what you provided, it doesn't print `New ad - traversing` for the first ad on the page, but it does for every new one afterwards. Why is that? The element is the same

Comment: I shared the html element in question in my main post above actually. Unless you want the whole DOM? In which case, it would be a great help if you can just visit the website and `inspect`. I have provided the link for it for that reason. Would be a great help. Personally can confirm I looked into those factors already, `js_` is a part of each ellipses element, otherwise i wouldnt want to use startwith(). Let me know if possible :)

Comment: so the reason you are skipping over the first element is that the current_element is not starting at the ellipsis element instead it is starting at `see ad details`. This is likely caused by starting at the wrong element when you initially click to tab to various selectable elements. The problem is that you select the initial element but then tab which changes the element - possibly change tabing to be at the end of the while loop?